# Asp.Net MVC Identity do not logout user if remember me is true?

Tags: asp.net-identity, session-cookies, remember-me

I am working on Login Functionality in Asp.Net MVC Project.

There are two scenarios in my application:

1. If remember me is false, and there is no interaction for 15 Minutes then I should logout user.
2. If remember me is true, then I should not logout user after minutes and clear the cookie after 5-hour.

I searched a lot on the internet and modified my `app.UseCookieAuthentication`:

It expires the session after 15-minute whether Remember Me is true or not? What am I doing wrong?

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
      // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
      // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
      OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(500),
        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)
      )
    },
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to this line:

```
ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
```

This means your cookie will **always** expire after 15 minutes.

You need check where the user submits the login form, if they have selected `Remember me?` then you will set `ExpireTimeSpan` to 5 hours, otherwise to 15 minutes.

**Update**

I'm not sure what your login code looks like but if you want different behaviour depending on if the user selects `Remember me?` you will need something similar to:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        IsPersistent = true,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20)
    });
```

More details and examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: How would I pass `ExpireTimeSpan` from Action to `ConfigureAuth`.

Comment: Have added an example. If you need further info can you please include your login method?